# Is it possible to serve static files with nginx/ubuntu from an nfs mount?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-10.04, nfs

I've been getting "403 permission denied" while using a nfs mount.

Any ideas?

NB: Disabled sendfile.

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SELinux or AppArmour installed? Either of these my block nfs file systems from being served.